# Search is extremely slow

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

The search functionality is broken, it seems, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=test only loads after more than a minute of waiting. This happens on multiple sites, e.g. also on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Confirmed here, using FF on Mac, I get the offline for maintenance page after a while

Comment: Is SE targeted again by bots?

Comment: The search of the Help center is also impacted, as is chat search.

Comment: search completely failed on meta mathematics whereas mathematics search queries dont return results

Comment: Search tends to cause tons of problems recently. Looks like heavy trolls chose this is a target, and SE running out of creative ideas how to stop them. :/

Comment: Turns out the previous search bug report was never fixed, so it's duplicate.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard IMO, this should not be considered a duplicate. Questions like this are trouble tickets. Such questions are how problems are reported to Stack Exchange. Closing this question as a duplicate implies that SE doesn't need to know that the problem is back, or that it's much more pronounced now. If a problem goes away and isn't affecting a large number of people for a considerable time (e.g. almost 2 months in this case), but then something similar starts happening, then it should be re-reported, which means posting a new question.

Comment: @Makyen I disagree. Same bug should not get more than one report, or else meta will be flooded with 1000 of the same bug report each time a major bug happens. Exception is when the bug is marked as [tag:status-completed], then if it's back, even same bug exactly, new report is the way to go.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard For all you know, the previous bug may have fixed itself before the team got around to responding to it, then this one could be a new bug. I'd let this question continue, and if it is indeed the same bug, SE staff can close it. I've seen that happen many times.

Comment: @Sonic the fact the exact same thing happens now proves the bug was never fixed. Neither by a developer, nor by itself. Something is broken.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard it is too early to call. This bug gets a second chance.

Comment: @rene Well I do stand behind my closure, but won't (and can't) fight further in case it's reopened. Let's just hope SE developers will also give it so much attention as we all do. :)

Comment: Now the search is working again... what happened??

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard There's nearly an unlimited number of different possible problems which could result in large numbers of people getting the "We are currently offline for maintenance" message. While I agree that reports that come in close together should be considered duplicates and closed as such. Alternately, problems that are very specific, but which may be reported over a large period of time (sometimes years), could be and should be duplicates. This one is quite general and until there's work done to isolate the issue, there's no way to know if it's actually a duplicate.

Comment: But, frankly, for something like this where the problem becomes much more prevalent and starts affecting large numbers of people, preventing them from using a significant feature of the site, Stack Exchange needs the problem report to be seen by people in the company who can work on fixing it. The way we have of communicating problems is through an open question here on MSE. So, even if this is actually the same problem as previously reported (which there's no way for us to know if it is until employees investigate), a question like this *needs* to stay open, so that it's seen and handled.

Comment: @Makyen again, I disagree. The outcome is 100% the same, and that's a fact: search does not work across all sites. I don't see a point to report it every time it happens while there is still an open and pending bug report exactly for that. As it turns out, SE developer reopened this one without any comment, I still think it's the same bug but I can't really do anything further.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard I understand you disagree. Frankly, at the moment, it doesn't matter if it's the same bug or not (there is *no way for us to actually know if it's really a duplicate*, without input from SE). What was *needed* is that it gets communicated to Stack Exchange employees that a problem has suddenly gotten severe, even if it's the same problem. The way that is done is by having an open question. Quickly closing the question as a duplicate of a *months old* problem report tends to *hide that information from SE*, which is detrimental to the overall functionality of the network.

Comment: It seems to be functioning okay now.

Comment: +1 to what @makyen wrote. Useful for us to keep active issues open, even if it's recurrence of an older issue (and not necessarily the same root cause)

Comment: «Useful for us to keep active issues open». I reckon only when they are of this urgent nature, bringing up a distinction that'd need to be made - urgent vs non-urgent (i see also why @Shadow10YearsWizard has that position, he sees tons of bugs being reported and some are just the same bug reported from a different user perspective and they're often linked through the usage of duplicates, that's a current on-going procedure).

Comment: @YaakovEllis [Uh-oh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357266/search-is-broken-again).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the nodes in our primary Elastic cluster has been having a few issues (we suspect a hardware issue at this point) that have resulted in it randomly re-allocating shards across nodes. For, as yet, unknown reasons it drastically degrades cluster performance resulting in timeouts and intermittently taking the entire cluster offline. We're in the process of increasing capacity in that cluster as well as provisioning a replacement search node for the one that keeps blipping.

For the moment we've moved search traffic over to our failover cluster while the capacity increase and replacement nodes happen in the primary cluster. It'll be a bit slower but won't completely break like before :)

Apologies for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 6):

For now the search functionality is completely broken, both on MSE and SO (and most likely network wide).
Search times out after a while and serves this beautiful page:

[image]

Comment: you mean networkwide https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=complex : shows no queries found
; I can confirm 20 minutes have already passed

Comment: Well probably yes @QueenieGoldstein, but I didn't have time to test all sites ;)