# Why was I able to post two identical answers to the same question 6 seconds apart?

Tags: bug, rate-limiting, duplication

Earlier today, I answered [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/58139/32651) on Law.SE.  When I posted my answer, I received a maintenance error page.  Assuming that my post had failed, I refreshed the page to resubmit it, and was redirected to my answer.  Later, I realized I'd posted two answers 6 seconds apart (see screenshots below).  Of course, I then deleted the second one.

According to [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/165261), no one (except for Staff users on meta sites) should be able to answer the same question twice within 60 seconds. I assume that limit exists to prevent things like this, where a user posts twice unintentionally, but it doesn't appear to have worked here.  Was this related to the fact that I hit an error page, or is the issue something else?

[image: Screenshot of answer showing a timestamp of 2020-11-16 14:46:10Z]
[image: Screenshot of deleted, otherwise identical answer showing a timestamp of 2020-11-16 14:46:16Z]

Comment: Similar, but with rate-limiting: [Was there a brief system glitch which caused some questions to be posted twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354028/282094).

Comment: Can [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356685/339911) be a reason?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Interesting...I'd be surprised, since I _assume_ Elastic just powers their search, but with no knowledge of SE's infrastructure, it's not impossible they're using it for rate-limiting somehow.

Comment: I just supposed due to the time proximity for these events.

Comment: How did you manage to show both tooltips in the same time?

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard two screenshots :-)

Comment: Huh! No gap whatsoever so didn't even think to check. Well done! :-D

Comment: Same thing happened here: [Window object properties behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64974995/4642212) (SO 10k link). This answer was identical to the existing one, but edited within the grace period. We now got [double-posted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346338/289905), [questions appearing twice in search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355174/289905), and double-posted answers…